# How to use snippets in comment and string

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

In Visual Studio Code, snippets is not work in comments or string. For example, I create snippet 't' for 'test', then type 't' in comment like

```
# t
```

or in string like

```
"this is a string t"
```

then there no suggestion and press 'tab' is not work.

How to use snippets in comment and string, in visual studio code?

Answer (score 6):

In `User Setting`, put the following:

> ```
> "editor.quickSuggestions": {
>     "comments": true,
>     "strings": true
>   },
> ```

Comment: How to find where to put it:
Command+P `settings.json`
or through the nav bar: Code > Preferences > Settings > search for 'quick' > click the result to 'edit in settings.json'

Comment: This also works for workspace settings (*/.vscode/settings.json*)